# Slicing volume in python

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

I am trying to show a function f(x,y,z), where x,y,z are vectors. I found a Matlab to do this, find below

```
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(-2:.2:2);
V = X.*exp(-X.^2-Y.^2-Z.^2);

xslice = [-1.2,0.8,2];   
yslice = [];
zslice = 0;
slice(X,Y,Z,V,xslice,yslice,zslice)
```

But, I am using python, and I can't find similar strategy in python. I found the plotly, but I can't use it. 
Can any one help me to reproduce this Matlab example in python.

Comment: could you provide what Python code you have tried?

Comment: Take a look at this [example](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/empet/Plotly-plots/blob/master/Plotly-Slice-in-volumetric-data.ipynb)

Comment: This is the error appears when using plotly                                          ImportError: 
The plotly.plotly module is deprecated,
please install the chart-studio package and use the
chart_studio.plotly module instead.

Comment: I don't know how to start in python